# When two rectangular matrices have the same row and null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$, $B$ be two $m \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ and $P$ and $Q$ are permutation matrices.
>
> (a) if the $\operatorname{nullspace}(A)=\operatorname{nullspace}(B)$, then $A=PB$.
>
> (b) if the $\operatorname{rowspace}(A)=\operatorname{rowspace}(B)$, then $A=BQ$.

My approach: two matrices have the same row space if one can be obtained from the other by using elementary row operations. That is, $A$ is obtained from $B$ using elementary row operations, that is, pre multiplied by elementary matrices (say, $E_i^s$). Since $E_i^s$ are non-singular matrices, then $A=B(E_i^s)^{-1}$. One last step to our goal is $E_i^s$ are easily converted into $Q$ using row operations. Hence, $A=BQ$.

Is this approach correct for (b)?

Answer (score 0):

There are some big issues with this question, too many to squeeze into a comment (or two), so I'm writing something that **may not be considered an answer**, but you may find helpful nonetheless. I suspect the most glaring of the issues is the fault of whomever gave you the question.

First, $\operatorname{nullspace} A = \operatorname{nullspace} B$ is actually *equivalent* to $\operatorname{rowspace} A = \operatorname{rowspace} B$! The reason is,
$$\operatorname{nullspace} A = (\operatorname{rowspace} A)^\perp,$$
i.e. the nullspace of a matrix is the set of vectors perpendicular to every vector in the rowspace. This is equivalent to
$$\operatorname{rowspace} A = (\operatorname{nullspace} A)^\perp,$$
and so we can recover the rowspace from the nullspace, and vice-versa.

This is because, due to the mechanics of matrix multiplication, when we multiply a matrix $A$ by a vector $x \in \Bbb{R}^m$, where $A$ has rows $r_1, \ldots, r_m$, the resulting vector is a vector of dot products:
$$Ax = \pmatrix{r_1 \cdot x \\ r_2 \cdot x \\ \vdots \\ r_m \cdot x}.$$
We have $Ax = 0$ if and only if $x$ is orthogonal to every row in $A$, or equivalently, every vector in the span of the rows, i.e. the rowspace.

This is already bad, because the existence of $P$ such that $A = PB$, and the existence of $Q$ such that $B = BQ$ are *not* equivalent. So, already the question has a serious hole in it.

Second, the use of "permutation" matrices seems to be incorrect (but I may be off the mark here). A permutation matrix is a square matrix containing only $0$s and $1$s, such that there is one and only one $1$ in each row (and column). For example,
$$P = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}$$
is a permutation matrix. Setting $A = PB$, where $P$ is a permutation matrix will not just give $A$ the same rowspace as $B$, it will give $A$ the same **rows** as $B$, just permute them to a (potentially) different order. However, other matrices will share the same rowspace, but not be a simple permutation of the rows. For example,
$$A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}, \qquad B = \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1}$$
both have a rowspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$, but they have different actual rows, i.e. there cannot be a permuation matrix $P$ such that $A = PB$.

*However*, this could be fixed by instead of insisting that $P$ be a *permutation* matrix, we could just insist that it is an *invertible* matrix. It is indeed true that $\operatorname{rowspace} A = \operatorname{rowspace} B$ (or equivalently with the nullspaces) if and only if there exists an *invertible* $P$ such that $A = PB$. You could try proving this with known results about elementary row operations and elementary matrices.

On the other hand, there exists *invertible* (not a permutation matrix, necessarily) $Q$ such that $A = BQ$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ have the same *columnspace*. You can try to prove this too.

One last comment: from $A$ and $B$ being row-equivalent, you get a sequence of elementary matrices $E_1, \ldots, E_k$ such that:
$$E_1 E_2 \ldots E_k A = B.$$
Note that it's not a single elementary matrix $E^s_i$, but a product. If you wanted to move these matrices to the other side of the equation, you would multiply both sides **on the left** by
$$(E_1 E_2 \ldots E_k)^{-1} = E_k^{-1} E_{k-1}^{-1} \ldots E_1^{-1}.$$
This would produce
$$E_k^{-1} E_{k-1}^{-1} \ldots E_1^{-1} E_1 E_2 \ldots E_k A = E_k^{-1} E_{k-1}^{-1} \ldots E_1^{-1} B,$$
i.e.
$$A = E_k^{-1} E_{k-1}^{-1} \ldots E_1^{-1} B.$$
Note that, unlike in your solution, the matrices stay on the left of $B$! This is, of course, important because matrix multiplication is not commutative.

I don't know if you'll be able to correct these issues with your question, but hopefully this has shed some light.